# Using BART's API to get a response using RestSharp C#

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, restsharp

I am trying to use the [BART's API](http://api.bart.gov/docs/stn/stns.aspx) to get a response using RestSharp. Here is what I have so far:

```
        var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("http://api.bart.gov/");
        var request = new RestRequest ("");
        request.AddParameter ("cmd", "stns");
        request.AddParameter ("key", "MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute (request);
```

This should get a list of all [Bart Stations](http://api.bart.gov/api/stn.aspx?cmd=stns&key=MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V). The `stns` parameter says to get all stations and the `key` is the API key.

However, when I try to print it out

```
Console.WriteLine (response.Content);
```

I get some weird document that says how to use BART API followed with some type of error that says

> Unknown Server (64-126)

Any ideas? I suspect it might be a simple error with how I have the Parameters set up or the way the client is set up.

Comment: `http://api.bart.gov/` Are you sure this shouldn't be `http://api.bart.gov/api/stn.aspx` ? See the bottom of your linked documentation: `Usage http://api.bart.gov/api/stn.aspx?cmd=stns&key=MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on their sample, the url to get a list of stations is `http://api.bart.gov/api/stn.aspx?cmd=stns&key=MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V`

If so, you want your request to look like:

```
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("http://api.bart.gov/");
var request = new RestRequest ("/api/stn.aspx");
request.AddParameter ("cmd", "stns");
request.AddParameter ("key", "MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute (request);
```